# Does timeout of apache has limit value?

Tags: apache, timeout

Does apache has limit to set timeout?
The default value is 300s.
I need raise the timeout to 2 hours.
Is it able to set the timeout to 7200？

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the file 
 `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
change

> Timeout 300
>   to
>   Timeout 7200

and restart apache